# eclipse indigo svnkit and proxy https howto

Tags: eclipse, svn, proxy, https, svnkit

sorry for asking this here, but only you will know :-)

I have a svn server and a proxy server between the server and my eclipse.

I have a proxy for doing https stuff which works perfectly in firefox.

Now I set my eclipse proxy stuff the same way but svn only shows "An error occurrred while accessing the repository entry"

Great. Someboby else said I have to change the servers file. Is this still true? What is best practise?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using Subclipse? 
 What OS are you on?

In Eclipse, have you configured your `> Window -> Preferences -> Network Connections`

to have your proxy server for HTTPS?

Do you have your repo setup as HTTPS?

Are you able to access your repo from other SVN clients?

I found this thread that might help you out a bit

(http://www.svnforum.org/archive/index.php/t-39672.html)